# How do I get an Alamofire Function result (Done) and set it to a value I can easily call in code later in Swift 3.1?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, function, swift3

I'm new to Swift 3. Here is my code:

```
func callYelp(completionHandler: @escaping (AnyObject) -> ()) {

Alamofire.request("https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search", parameters: getParameters, headers: headers)
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            //print("JSON: \(json)")
            let arrayNames =  json["businesses"].arrayValue.map({$0["name"].stringValue})
            let arrayRating =  json["businesses"].arrayValue.map({$0["rating"].stringValue})
            print(arrayNames, arrayRating)

            completionHandler(arrayNames as AnyObject)


        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
}
```

How can I call it as so and set it to a variable?

```
callYelp() { responseObject in
        print(responseObject)
        return
    }
```

such as this:

var fruits = the function call.

Thanks

Comment: Could you rephrase what you are asking? Are you wanting to try and set var fruits = callYelp()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this directly, as you intend to. As all the Alamofire functions run *asynchronously*, you can't tell exactly when you'll have a result, and in fact the `Alamofire.request` method only gives you an object which you can latch a callback onto using `responseJSON` or another handler such as `responseString`. You have no control over when this callback will be called - it will run when the request is done.

Since all we can do with a `Request` is add a callback to it, it follows that we must use the callback in order to do *anything* with the result of the call. Fortunately, you can specify the callback as a closure, and closures have a special property: They *close over* their execution environment (hence the name) which means all variables available in the lexical environment where the closure is created are also available inside the function.

This means that this is perfectly valid code:

```
var fruits: [String] = []
callYelp() { responseObject in
    fruits = responseObject
}
```

If you need to get notified of when `fruits` gets set by the callback (as you have no control over when the callback actually gets called) you might want to add a [`didSet` observer](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#PropertyObservers) to `fruits`:

```
var fruits: [String] = [] {
    didSet {
        //handle anything that needs to be handled
        //when you get data
    }
}
callYelp() {
    fruits = $0
}
```

In this last example, I used shorthand closure argument syntax, where instead of naming each closure argument, you can use the implicit names `$0`, `$1` and so on.